# How to use tiled map without Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, tile

I know how to use tiled maps (.tmx files) with cocos2d. But I want to use it without Cocos2d. Can i do that? If yes, How?

Comment: Uhm, cocos2d IS a native iOS framework. When you code for it you are still using 'native iOS'.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII . Right. Sorry for wrong words. I need to use it without cocos2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TMX` file format is [documented in the Tiled wiki](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format).  It's an XML-based format.  iOS comes with two XML parsers to choose from:

- The event-driven [`NSXMLParser` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), also discussed in the [*Event-Driven XML Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i).
- [`libxml2`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which has both event-driven and parse-tree-producing interfaces, and is documented at [its own web site](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html).